# Sed multi-line replace over escaped strings

Tags: postgresql, regex, sed

I'm attempting to convert a mysqldump output file to PostgreSQL compatible SQL. The issue is in dealing with escaped string values.

I need to go from:

```
VALUES('blah blah blah','second string \'with escaped\'
quotes 
and multiple lines goes here',35,10,'meh')
```

to:

```
VALUES(E'blah blah blah',E'second string \'with escaped\'
quotes 
and multiple lines goes here',35,10,E'meh')
```

Notice the addition of the "E" before each single-quoted string.

How can this be accomplished in sed? Also open to using other regex engines as long as I can stream them (dealing with multi-GB files here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me that this is not an uncommon usage scenario, so I checked PostgreSQL's site to see if they have solutions -- and indeed they list [several tools to do the job](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Scripts.2C_programs). Hopefully one of them works for you.